# Error: Instalando Magento2

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, magento2

Estoy instalando magento2 en Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal mail, la instalación fue satisfactoria, pero al intentar ingresar a http://localhost/, solo veo la página principal del nginx.

Mi archivo de configuración en el NGINX es:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

server {
     server_name localhost;
     listen 80;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /opt/magento2;
     set $MAGE_MODE developer;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/magento2-access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/magento2-error.log;

     include /opt/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Posteriormente hago la configuración del magento:

```
sudo -u www-data bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://localhost/"
```

Finalmente reinicio el NGINX:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Pero solo logro ver el index.html del NGINX

```
Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

Alguna idea????

Comment: Si deseas instalar Magento2 en Ubuntu 22.04 con Apache2, te dejo mis siguientes tutoriales: 1. [Como instalar Apache2 en Ubuntu 22.04 para usar Magento2](https://gersonhernandez.net/instalar-servidor-web-apache2-en-ubuntu-22-04/) 2. [Como configurar Apache2 en Ubuntu 22.04 para usar Magento2](https://gersonhernandez.net/como-configurar-un-servidor-web-apache2-en-ubuntu-22-04-para-usar-magento2/) 3. [Como crear un vHost Apache2 en Ubuntu 22.04 para usar Magento2](https://gersonhernandez.net/como-crear-un-virtual-host-vhost-con-apache2-en-ubuntu-22-04-para-usar-magento2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de estar lidiando con este error, la solución fue más sencillo de lo que pensé. Bastó con reinstalar Magento y automáticamente funcionó.

Para desinstalar use:

```
cd /opt/magento2

sudo bin/magento setup:uninstall
```

Y una vez desinstalado, procedí a reinstalar usando:

```
sudo bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost --db-host=localhost --db-name=magentodb --db-user=magento --db-password=my_password --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=adgarcia@kionetworks.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=es_MX --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1


sudo chown -R www-data. /opt/magento2

sudo -u www-data bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

sudo -u www-data bin/magento cache:flush

sudo -u www-data bin/magento cron:install
```

Todo el crédito lo tiene el siguiente link: [Instalación Magento 2.4.4 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-install-magento-2-4-4-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta desactivando el sitio predeterminado `sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` o deja `-base-url="http://localhost/magento`

Comment: Funcionó correctamente, muchísimas gracias.  Ahora, solo me queda una situación, no me permite entrar al Magento Admin URI, lo instalé usando composer y me dio una URL del tipo {http://localhost/admin_sj6sin}

Comment: Cuando dices que no te permite, te refieres a que no carga o note acepta el usuario y contraseña?

Comment: Me forza a usar https y si pongo la URL como http://localhost/admin me arroja un "No se puede acceder a este sitio"